# Running all unit tests in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm working on a Flutter project and trying to find the best way to structure my tests. Typically I structure tests to mirror the directory structure of the main project which is being tested.

```
lib
 |models
 |providers
   |userprovider.dart
test
 lib
   |models
   |providers
     |userproviderShould.dart
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out if this approach is less than optimal for the Dart code. Each file in the test project seems to need to have a `main` method, which feels odd. I'm also not clear on how to run the entire test suite. The Flutter test running (`flutter test`) doesn't seem to understand directories. Running `flutter test test/lib/providers` doesn't work while `flutter test test/lib/providers/userproviderShould.dart` does. If it doesn't understand directories it certainly doesn't understand having to recurse into directories.

Is there a way to solve this that doesn't involve either having to build a fragile entry point that manually includes all the rest of the tests or writing a shell script to go run each file individually?

Comment: I noticed an issue you raised wasn't discussed/talked about re: mirror project structure. Assuming you start off with the 'right' project structure, it seems somewhat tedious to rearrange then mirror changes. What did you end up doing to address this issue?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want `flutter test` or `pub run test` to execute a file without manually passing its path as parameter to the command, then the file must:

- be inside the `/test` folder
- its name must be suffixed by `_test.dart`

Anything that does not have this `_test` will not be executed by the command line.

Comment: But how to run all the tests from different modules in a flutter project using a single command?

Comment: @sagarsuri check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69123248/915875

Comment: @sagarsuri You can run all tests in your project using `flutter test . packages/*` (as long as all of your modules live in a `packages` directory)

Answer (score 18):

To run all the unit tests in a project, type one of the following commands in the terminal while in the root of your project:

### Flutter project

```
flutter test
```

### Dart project

```
dart test
```

### Notes

- Dart projects used to be `pub run test`. You can probably still do that but `dart test` is the new way to do it and is also easier to remember.
- [test package documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/test)
- You may need to run `flutter pub get` or `dart pub get` to retrieve the test package if you haven't previously.

Answer (score 5):

With Flutter 2.5 (and perhaps below, though I haven't checked), apparently, you can use any directory name as an argument and it'll run all `**/*_test.dart` files in it.

So: `flutter test lib` does the trick! You can pass additional arguments to the command, as long as the directory name is the very last argument (`flutter test --no-pub --coverage lib`).

Docs: https://pub.dev/packages/test#running-tests

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, the **`flutter test`** or **`dart test`** (for tests that don't need the flutter SDK) commands will run anything under your `test/` dir by default whose filename ends in `_test.dart`. (See the [test](https://pub.dev/packages/test#running-tests) package and [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing).)

However, if you're expecting to see nice output per test on the command line, you won't since the default `--reporter` type is compact, showing only a single line updated dynamically. Furthermore, since tests are run concurrently  by default (see `--concurrency=<jobs>` flag), it's possible one test's message will stomp on another's even when using `--reporter expanded`. If you really want to see a friendly line per test, limit concurrency with:

**`flutter test -j 1 -r expanded`**

Other notes:

- There's a lot of options one can pass to `flutter/dart test`. See e.g. `flutter test --help`
- `dart test` was introduced as of Dart 2.10 - prior sdk versions must use `pub run test`
- `flutter pub test` is equivalent to `pub run test` which is now `dart test` as noted above. `flutter pub test --help` states:

> This is similar to "flutter test", but instead of hosting the tests in the flutter environment it hosts the tests in a pure Dart environment. The main differences are that the "dart:ui" library is not available and that tests run faster. This is helpful for testing libraries that do not depend on any packages from the Flutter SDK.

Comment: I have many of both unit and widget tests and I didn't believe other answers - there were no real evidence that all tests passed, `-r expanded` output was weird. But your approach proves that all tests pass indeed. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

For commands, other answers here show you can use `flutter test` and `dart test` ( from @Suragch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031862/1433980) )

About your `flutter test test/lib/providers` not working, try using `test/lib/providers/*` instead, because that worked for me when I had a similar issue.

---

If you're using VS Code, for a launch command (by pressing `F5`) you can go to the `Run and debug` tab, and at the top-right of that sidebar, click the gear/settings icon which opens your `launch.json`, where you can add this section:

```json
{
  "name": "Dart: Run all tests",
  "type": "dart",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "./test/"
},
```

To hotkey this launch command, just go back to the `Run and debug` tab and at the top, use the dropdown menu to select the "name" of it, which will set it to launch by default when you press `F5`

And you can add more sections with different names and test folders for targeted tests that you'd want to launch quickly, e.g.

```json
{
  "name": "Run user tests",
  "type": "dart",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "./test/users/"
},
```